# StdOut From Windows GUI Shows in Console But isn't Logged

Tags: batch-file, console, labview

I am launching LabVIEW from a batch file to automate a build. From my build step I am printing to StdOut by doing the following within LabVIEW with .NET and the Windows API-- I am going to use some pseudo code here:

```
process=GetCurrentProcess()
handle=process.GetCurrentHandle()
int32Value=handle.ToInt32()
GetStdHandle(-11)
DuplicateHandle(bunch of inputs)

If Duplicate Handle Fails
{
   AttachConsole
}
Console.Write("I write this string")
```

Anyways, this works and prints my string to the console. But, while this text prints, it isn't redirected to a file when I try redirection.

```
set STDOUT=stdout.log
start /wait LabVIEW.exe "C:\Users\<username>\Desktop\BuildSuccess.vi" 1>> C:\%STDOUT%
```

The fact that it isn't redirected to a file makes me think that there is some issue with the reference I have to StdOut even though it's printed to the console. The reason I don't just write a file directly from LabVIEW is because ultimately I want Bamboo to capture my StdOut (as it seems it already does with other commands I echo) and log to its file automagically. But, these strings weren't showing up in that log file which lead me down this path.

I know I'm effectively trying to write to a console from a Windows GUI which, from what I've read, seems to be somewhat of a faux pas, so I am not opposed to writing to a file, then reading that file via my batch script and echoing it out. But, I figured I'd give this a shot.

Edit: It looks like my DuplicateHandle is failing and so it will then attach to the console and print there instead. I will look into that.

Edit 2: New info, which somewhat confirms what I thought. This is irrespective of edit #1:

```
@echo off
cd "C:\Program Files (x86)\National Instruments\LabVIEW 2013"
FOR /F "tokens=*" %%G IN ('start /wait LabVIEW.exe %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\BuildSuccess.vi"') DO 
(printf "I am echoing the variable:\n" %%G)
```

This code never prints anything from the for loop, yet I still see text on the console that my application directly writes. This makes me think it's like the text my application is printing to the console isn't recognized as stdout from said application

Comment: Do you really try to create a log file in root of drive C: as this is not possible without administrator privileges by default since Windows Vista? And use `%USERPROFILE%` instead of `C:\Users\<username>` in batch file. You can use `type "CreatedLogFile.log"` in your batch file if decision is taken to write first to a file and next output it in batch file.

Comment: Ultimately I will not actually write to C; this was just for testing purposes and I'm running as Admin. Also, this remains unsolved, I have direction but not a solution. Thanks for the tip on using type. I will probably go this route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I launched with start /b instead of start /wait and the output was redirected to a file.